# Fastest way to generate PNG tiles from a KML file

Tags: postgis, geometry, kml, png, optimization

I have several KML files and each KML is being parsed, turned into a geometry with PostGIS' `ST_GeomFromKML()` and saved to a database. This database is parsed and uses `ST_AsPng()` to process each geometry at a specific zoom level and saves the PNGs locally. The problem is that each zoom level has to be done individually and each zoom level takes a long time. It takes specially long since its querying the database.

Any idea on how to speed this process up?

As of now, to generate the PNG tiles I'm using Java with multiple threads doing queries for `ST_asPng()`.

Comment: Have you thought about using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) to render the tiles directly with out using PostGIS - or even easier using [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) to do all the hard work automatically

Comment: @IanTurton Would I be able to extract all the Polygons directly from the KML file using GeoTools?

Comment: of course, and style them and draw directly to a PNG